# Override Task in build.gradle

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, dynatrace

How to override a task in `build.gradle` ?

I trying to compile the `build.gradle` with the dependency `Dynatrace`, a conflict between task names is occurring.

> Error: Cannot add task ':app:autoInstrumentDebug' as a task with that
>   name already exists.

I have checked my current tasks on `build.gradle` menu and don't have found any task with this path name.

Comment: can you show your build.gradle and command you are executing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you should try overwriting the task (make sure to test well the App afterwards to avoid unwanted side-effects).

In order to you should do the following:

```
task(overwrite: true){
apply plugin: 'com.name.of.your.plugin'
plugin {
    defaultConfig {

    }
}}
```

I hope this helps you buddy! I'm sure you're coworkers will be very proud of you!